# javascript function not accepting passed Object variables

Tags: javascript, function, argument-passing

I'm trying to modify a javascript accordian menu to fit my boss's needs. However, now that I've made most of the adjustments, I've hit a virtual brick wall. The function expandInit() is not accepting the arguments I'm passing to it. I keep getting the "Object expected" error, but i've tested the arguments for the function using typeof() and it returns that the argument is an Object. So I'm stumped, any light that anyone could shed on this would be very helpful.

Here's the pertinent code:

```
function $(id){
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function expandTimer(div){
  if(getHeight(div) < div.maxh){
    var velocity = Math.round((div.maxh - getHeight(div)) / div.speed);
    velocity = (velocity < 1) ? 1 : v;
    velocity = (getHeight(div) + velocity);
    setHeight(div, velocity+'px');
    div.style.opacity = (velocity / div.maxh);
    div.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity = '+(velocity * 100 / div.maxh)+');';
  } else {
    setHeight(div, div.maxh);
    clearInterval(div.refRate);
  }
}

//arg types are String, Int, and, String.
function accordian(mother, speed, alternate){
  var motherObj = $(mother);
  motherObj.activeNode='';
  var allDivs = motherObj.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++){
    var divID = allDivs[i].id;
    if (divID.substr(divID.indexOf('-') + 1, divID.length) == 'header'){
      var contentID = divID.substr(0, divID.indexOf('-'))+'-content';
      var divObj = $(divID);
      divObj.contentNode = contentID;
      divObj.hightlight = alternate;
      var contentObj = $(contentID);
      contentObj.style.display = 'none';
      contentObj.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      contentObj.maxh = getHeight(contentObj);
      contentObj.speed = speed;
      contentObj.refRate;
      divObj.onmouseover = function(){
        if (this.parentNode.activeNode != ''){
          collapseInit($(this.parentNode.activeNode));
        }
        alert (typeof($(this.contentNode))); //returns 'object'
        //code executes fine up until here.
        expandInit($(this.contentNode));
        this.parentNode.activeNode = this.contentNode;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Although I didn't include the collapseInit() code, it is having the same problem. Suffice to say that all the other functions referenced above work as intended.

EDIT: Sorry, didn't include the right function. Here's the expandInit() function:

```
function expandInit(div){
  alert("in expandInit"); //<---does not execute.
  setDisplay(div,'block');
  div.style.height='0px';
  clearInterval(div.refRate);
  div.refRate = setInterval('expandTimer('+div+')', 10);
}
```

Comment: What is `expandInit`? Could you link or paste the definition?

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache (it might have kept the old Js code) ?

Comment: `typeof($(this.contentNode))` will always be `object`, even if `this.contentNode` is `undefined` or `null` because it's a jQuery object.  You probably need to see what `this.parentNode.activeNode` actually is (look in the debugger).  If you need further help, then please include the code for `expandInit()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 OP is not using jQuery, the dollar function is declared to be shorthand in this case for getElementById

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an expandInit function there, but I do see an expandTimer function...

Comment: function expandInit(div){
 alert("in expandInit");
 setDisplay(div,'block');
 div.style.height='0px';
 clearInterval(div.refRate);
 div.refRate = setInterval('expandTimer('+div+')', 10);
 }
}